# How do I extract a submatrix from a matrix in ruby

Tags: ruby, matrix

What would be the idiomatic way of extracting a submatrix from a matrix in ruby.

I have a matrix like, this is an object of `Matrix`

```
[131, 673, 234, 103, 18]
[201, 96, 342, 965, 150]
[630, 803, 746, 422, 111] 
[537, 699, 497, 121, 956] 
[805, 732, 524, 37, 331]
```

I'm looking for a method with a signature like
`matrix.submatrix(1,1)` this should return

```
[96, 342, 965, 150]
[803, 746, 422, 111] 
[699, 497, 121, 956] 
[732, 524, 37, 331]
```

`matrix.submatrix(2,2)` would return

```
[746, 422, 111] 
[497, 121, 956] 
[524, 37, 331]
```

I browsed through the [rubydoc](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html) but couldn't find any method that would give me what I wanted. How would I do this in ruby?

For a 2D array I have come up with

```
def submatrix(matrix)
  submatrix = matrix.collect{|row| row.slice(1..-1)}
  # Pop off the first row
  submatrix[1..-1]
end
```

I am wondering if I should reinvent the wheel or could I use something from the Matrix class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Ruby 2.2.0 or later, you can use [Matrix#first_minor](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-trunk/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html#method-i-first_minor), which removes a specified row and column.  I'm not sure how efficient it is, but here is some code that solves your problem:

```
require 'matrix'

def my_submatrix(matrix, n)
  matrix = matrix.first_minor(0, 0) while matrix.row_count > n
  matrix
end

m = Matrix[[131, 673, 234, 103, 18],
           [201, 96, 342, 965, 150],
           [630, 803, 746, 422, 111],
           [537, 699, 497, 121, 956],
           [805, 732, 524, 37, 331]]

p my_submatrix(m, 3)
# => Matrix[[746, 422, 111], [497, 121, 956], [524, 37, 331]]
```

Answer (score 10):

Take a look at [Matrix#minor](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html#method-i-minor):

```
a = [[131, 673, 234, 103, 18], 
     [201, 96, 342, 965, 150], 
     [630, 803, 746, 422, 111], 
     [537, 699, 497, 121, 956], 
     [805, 732, 524, 37, 331]]

m = Matrix[*a]

m1 = m.minor(1..4, 1..4)
=> Matrix[[96, 342, 965, 150],  [803, 746, 422, 111], 
          [699, 497, 121, 956], [732, 524, 37, 331]]

m2 = m1.minor(1..3, 1..3)
=> Matrix[[746, 422, 111], [497, 121, 956], [524, 37, 331]]
```

You can also do:

```
m1 = m.minor(1..-1, 1..-1)
m2 = m1.minor(1..-1, 1..-1)
```

Or:

```
class Matrix
  def submatrix(x, y)
    self.minor(x..-1, y..-1)
  end
end

m.submatrix(2, 2)
=> Matrix[[746, 422, 111], [497, 121, 956], [524, 37, 331]]
```

Comment: Your upper-bounds in the first example are one larger than they need be. (E.g. `m.minor(1..5, 1..5) == m.minor(1..4, 1..4)` & `m1.minor(1..4, 1..4) == m1.minor(1..3, 1..3)`.)

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple of ways, one using a `Matrix` object, the other just manipulating an array.

**Manipulating a `Matrix` object**

**Code**

```
require 'matrix'

def doit(matrix,i,j)
   selection_matrix(matrix.row_count,i) * matrix *
      selection_matrix(matrix.row_size,j)
end

def selection_matrix(n,m)
  Matrix.diagonal(*(0...n).map { |i| (i<m) ? 0 : 1 })
end
```

Use `doit(matrix,i,j).to_a` to return an `Array` object.

**Examples**

```
a = [[131, 673, 234, 103,  18], 
     [201, 96,  342, 965, 150], 
     [630, 803, 746, 422, 111], 
     [537, 699, 497, 121, 956], 
     [805, 732, 524,  37, 331]]

matrix = Matrix[*a]
doit(matrix,2,2)
  #=> Matrix[[0, 0,   0,   0,   0],
  #          [0, 0,   0,   0,   0],
  #          [0, 0, 746, 422, 111],
  #          [0, 0, 497, 121, 956],
  #          [0, 0, 524,  37, 331]]

doit(matrix,1,1)
  #=> Matrix[[0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
  #          [0,  96, 342, 965, 150],
  #          [0, 803, 746, 422, 111], 
  #          [0, 699, 497, 121, 956],
  #          [0, 732, 524,  37, 331]]
```

**Explanation**

`selection_matrix(n,m)` returns a diagonal matrix whose diagonal elements are ones and zeros, the ones stabing out the appropriate rows or columns of the matrix.  The matrix is pre-multiplied (post-multiplied) by a diagonal matrix whose order equals the number of rows (columns) of the matrix.

```
selection_matrix(5,2)
  #=> Matrix[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  #          [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  #          [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
  #          [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
  #          [0, 0, 0, 0, 1]]

a = selection_matrix(5,2) * matrix
  #=> Matrix[[  0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
  #          [  0,   0,   0,   0,   0],
  #          [630, 803, 746, 422, 111],
  #          [537, 699, 497, 121, 956],
  #          [805, 732, 524,  37, 331]]

b = a * selection_matrix(5,2)
  #=> Matrix[[0, 0,   0,   0,   0],
  #          [0, 0,   0,   0,   0],
  #          [0, 0, 746, 422, 111],
  #          [0, 0, 497, 121, 956],
  #          [0, 0, 524,  37, 331]]

b.to_a
  #=>       [[0, 0,   0,   0,   0],
  #          [0, 0,   0,   0,   0],
  #          [0, 0, 746, 422, 111],
  #          [0, 0, 497, 121, 956],
  #          [0, 0, 524,  37, 331]]
```

**Manipulating an `Array` object**

Without creating a `Matrix` object, you could just do this:

**Code**

```
def doit(a,i,j)
  a[i..-1].transpose[j..-1].transpose
end
```

**Examples**

```
a = [[131, 673, 234, 103,  18], 
     [201,  96, 342, 965, 150], 
     [630, 803, 746, 422, 111], 
     [537, 699, 497, 121, 956], 
     [805, 732, 524,  37, 331]]

doit(a,1,1)
  #=> [[ 96, 342, 965, 150],
  #    [803, 746, 422, 111],
  #    [699, 497, 121, 956],
  #    [732, 524,  37, 331]]

doit(a,2,2)
  #=> [[746, 422, 111],
  #    [497, 121, 956],
  #    [524,  37, 331]]
```